# Does storing my database as a .sql file in my site git repository cause problems?

Tags: 7, database, version-control

I have been saving a series of database export files each time I do a git commit of my Drupal site.  I have a nice git repository for my site files and a messy folder for my database backups.  Because the database file is related to a commit, should the database file be included with the Drupal site files (in a temporary folder of some kind?)  It seems helpful to bind these files together in a single commit.  However, this practice does not seem commonplace, so there may be a problem with it.  Have I overlooked a major issue?

If so, would it be better to create another repository for my database backups?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the right way  so that both site & database are in sync.

I'd suggest you better backup the (zipped) mysql dump from [backup-migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate%E2%80%8E) module. If you can use lzma compression then you can save another 20% space on mysql backups using this way.

Comment: I'm considering keeping it unzipped so that the file can be diff-ed